# Why do some questions start with a magic invocation?

Tags: discussion

I don't mean "Hi Everybody" or "I hope someone can help me" or even "I've tried a search but can't find anything." I mean

> 0 down vote favorite

example here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/30153/285 and it's not the first time I've seen it. Is it a marker of some kind of copying and pasting?

Comment: I was thinking the same exact thing.  What does the mean???  I was thinking it was some kind of cryptic instruction that we needed to follow...

Comment: A quick check of the [question's source](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/revisions/54c861ac-0d11-4574-87e0-f064f5fd66f3/view-source) reveals that the user actually entered that. You'll have to ask them why they did it :)

Answer (score 13):

If you drag-select the text of a question, starting at the end and ending at the beginning...

And you overshoot a bit...

...you end up selecting the vote count (0), the down-vote arrow (down vote) and the star (favorite). The text on the latter two is normally hidden by the stylesheet in favor of an image, but the vote number allows it to be selected and copied.

(Now, I have no idea what these users are doing copying and then pasting a question *into* another question... Cross-posting? Ahhh... [Manual migration!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535311/programmer-coach-wanted-to-learn-vb-net))

Comment: Excellent work my dear Mr. Holmes!